# Infinite Integral of a Bessel Function

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I need to calculate the following integral

$$
\int_0^{\infty}xdxJ_n(kx)
$$

Integrating it by parts and using the normalization of Bessel functions, I find it (somewhat heuristically) to equal the Dirac Delta function $\delta(k)$. I cannot find a single source online or in a reference like Abramowitz and Stegun to back this up. Can someone here confirm this?

Comment: With regularization I have:$$\int_0^{\infty } x J_n(k x) \, dx=\frac{n}{k^2}$$. See:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304388/regularization-of-integral

Answer (score 2):

The integral
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} x\, J_n(x)\,dx $$
**is not** converging for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, since $J_n(x)$ decays like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ as $x\to +\infty$.

On the other hand, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} J_n(x)\,dx = 1 $$
since:
$$ \mathcal{L}(J_n(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}\left(s+\sqrt{1+s^2}\right)^n}.$$

Comment: I understand the argument against it being convergent, but my question was whether it could be expressed in terms of the Dirac distribution (which is formally not convergent?). For example, the n=0 case is easily seen to be equal to the Dirac delta function in 2D polar coordinates. I was hoping it could be similarly expressed for n>0.

Comment: @dbrane: we cannot make convergent what is not. The Dirac distribution is not defined pointwise but its Lebesgue integral over the real line is one. $x J_n(x)$ is neither Riemann or Lebesgue integrable over the real line, so I do not see any connection between the Dirac distribution and this non-existing integral, even in the $n=0$ case.