# Regularization of integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, divergence-operator, regularization

How does one regularize a divergent integral of the form,
$$
I = \int_0^\infty dx \, \cosh^4 x \hspace{0.5 in} ?
$$
Regularizing via simple subtraction of divergences (as we commonly do in physics) is not a viable option, since expanding $\cosh^4x$ in a power series reveals an infinite number of divergent contributions, with no finite piece to remain. However, I do know that there must be some regularization technique out there enabling us to evaluate this, since we have a similar result
$$
\int_0^\infty dx \, \cosh^4 x \sinh x = -{8 \pi \over 15}
$$
in common use. Any tips on how to obtain this sort of thing  (or even reference to a source where this is calculated) would be very helpful!

Comment: A regularization is just a way to extend the concept of convergence in a mathematical framework, nothing grants that the chosen regularization is really meaningful in a physical context. You should mention the actual reason generating the need for such integral to have a finite value.

Comment: For instance, in the $\zeta$-regularization sense we have $\sum_{n\geq 1}n = -\frac{1}{12}$, but that the sum of positive quantities is negative is kind of unacceptable in a physical way.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio in some way physics suggests that the regularization you mentioned is indeed the correct way to interpret this sum: see Casimir effect for example :)

Comment: Your second result looks wrong to me. Where did you get it? My answer is $-1/5$ for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may note that:

$$I=\int_0^\infty\cosh^4(x)~\mathrm dx=\frac1{16}\int_0^\infty e^{4x}+4e^{2x}+6+4e^{-2x}+e^{-4x}~\mathrm dx$$

Using $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}~\mathrm dx=\frac1a$, we may regularize our integral to

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac38~\mathrm dx$$

Which may be regularized to $\frac38\zeta(0)=-\frac3{16}$.

Same method for the second integral.

Comment: What's the justification for the regularization $\int_0^\infty 1 \,\mathrm{d}x = \zeta(0)$?

Comment: Consider this regularization: $\int_0^\infty 1 \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \mathrm{e}^{-x\varepsilon}(1-x\varepsilon) \,\mathrm{d}x \overset{!}{=} \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x\varepsilon}(1-x\varepsilon) \,\mathrm{d}x =\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} 0 = 0$.

Comment: Everything is OK except the last step. $I=\int_0^\infty\frac38~\mathrm dx=\frac38 \int_0^\infty dx=0$

Comment: @user76284 I absolutely agree. This only can be regularized to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Simply Beautiful Art is totally wrong because of his last step.

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac38~\mathrm dx=\frac38 \int_0^\infty 1 dx=\frac38\left(\int_0^{1/2}1dx+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1\right)=\frac38(\frac12-\frac12)=0$$

The last integral can only be regularized to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is wrong, I do not know your source, but the correct answer is $-1/5$. This can be seen using two different methods, one using Laplace transform and the other reducing the problem to Dirichlet regularization of a series.

Here is the code in Mathematica and results of regularizing your examples and another function using the both methods:
[image]

```
Regularize := 
 Inactivate[reg[Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]], Integrate] == 
   Limit[s Sum[f[s x], {x, 1, Infinity}, 
       Regularization -> "Dirichlet"] // FullSimplify, s -> 0] // 
  TraditionalForm
Regularize2 := 
 Inactivate[reg[Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]], Integrate] == 
   Evaluate[
    Evaluate[LaplaceTransform[ f[t], t, x]] /. x -> 0 // 
     FullSimplify] // TraditionalForm
```

For the function $\cosh^4(x)$ one of the methods fails but the other works.